# Are there any differences between 申込/申し込み and 応募?

Tags: word-choice

I appreciate that both 申込 and 応募 basically mean "application". Are there any subtle differences, or nuances to consider when choosing which one to use? Is one more formal than the other for example?

Comment: From what I recall, application (like an application form / register) for the first, and application (for a jop position) for the other. http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/thsrs/11075/meaning/m0u/%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F/

Comment: Kenkyūsha's 応募  entry includes many examples  where it means "subscription" (応募価格  "subscription price"; 株式[国債]募集に応募する "subscribe for shares [government bonds]"), besides some examples as "application". 申し込み seems to be more centered on "application, request".  it also has several specialized uses/collocations, like "challenge (to a duel)" or "offer (of marriage)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      おうぼ【応募】とは。 ［名］(スル) 募集に応じること。「コンクールに― する」 「―者」
```

Sometimes 応募 and 公募 and 募集 seem to be used like synonyms, as in :

> - 特にメディア業界の求人は人気が高いため、応募が出ていたとしても、すぐに締め切られてしまうことも多いようです。
> - 現在、次の仕事先を探しています。 たまたま以前から勤めたい企業の応募が出ていたので応募したいのですが、いつ、今の仕事を辞められるか分からないので・・・

---

申し込み is the action.   --  You can do 申し込み (application) to a 応募 or 公募.

> - iPhone・スマートフォンから応募に申し込む場合は、お問合せフォームに下記の内容を入力し、送信してください。 お名前; メールアドレス; 電話番号; ご用件の種類; メッセージ. 後ほど、担当者より詳細についてご連絡を差し上げます。
> - メンバーズポイントを消費して、希望するアイテムの抽選応募に申し込むことができます。 厳選なる抽選の上、当選発表日に、当選者にのみ ........
> - 友人と話し合った結果CD購入の応募に申し込むことなりました。

I think 応募 suggests a possibility of being rejected, whereas 申し込み may not.

応募 is more formal and less personal than 申し込み

Net-searching hits

- "結婚プロポーズ" ----> 約 67,900 件
- "結婚申し込み"  ----> 約 15,200 件
- "結婚応募"  ----> 約 440 件

> http://thejapanesepage.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=13920
>   結婚, 決闘, and 議事録の閲覧 are not considered 募集, so you don't use 応募する.

Great point !

Comment: "結婚**の**申し込み"なら８万件を超えますが。（←その方が自然ですしね・・・。）「応募に申し込む」...(?_?)

Comment: `You can do 申し込み (application) to a 応募 or 公募.` <- You don't 申し込む to 応募. The use of 応募 and 申し込む in your examples 「応募に申し込む場合は」「抽選応募に申し込むことができます」「応募に申し込むことなりました」are grammatically incorrect. You can say 募集に応募する or 募集に申し込む, but [応募に申し込む (only 38 hits)](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%E3%81%AB%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%22&ei=ShD2V-HgCMbZjwTbmKmQAw&start=30&sa=N),

Comment: (cont.) [申し込みに応募(56 hits)](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%E3%81%AB%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%22&ei=ShD2V-HgCMbZjwTbmKmQAw&start=30&sa=N#q=%22%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%22&start=50) or [応募に応募(91 hits)](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%E3%81%AB%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80%22&ei=ShD2V-HgCMbZjwTbmKmQAw&start=30&sa=N#q=%22%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%E3%81%AB%E5%BF%9C%E5%8B%9F%22&start=90) are incorrect.  `応募 suggests a possibility of being rejected, whereas 申し込み may not` <- Both can be rejected.

Comment: The use of 応募 in your first two examples 「 **応募**が出ていたとしても、すぐに締め切られてしまう」「企業の**応募**が出ていたので応募したい」are also incorrect (応募 means 募集に応じる, and how can anyone 申し込む/応募する to a 募集に応じること?) These should be 「 **募集**が出ていたとしても、すぐに締め切られてしまう」「企業の**募集**が出ていたので応募したい」. Please don't quote grammatically incorrect sentences just blindly from the web.  あのね、間違った・おかしな例文を、やみくもに引用して、正しい用例みたいに紹介するの、やめてもらえませんかね。引用する前に、あってるかどうか精査できないんですかね？